# Parent cannot move child when child have nCloth

Tags: transforms, cloth-simulation, parent

I am a new blender user.

I am currently having issues moving the child (have modifiers, particleSystems and nCloth attached) when animating parent.

How do I go about it and why is it acting this way?

Any help will be greatly appreciated thank you!

File:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the simulation is baked or played from the cache, it moves the mesh according to global coordinates (other than a Mantaflow simulation which is bound to its domain and can be moved around with it).

So when you try to move the cloth with a parent object, the simulation will move the mesh's vertices where they should be in global positions due to their simulated location.

If the simulation is baked, even moving the object directly without being parented to another object will make the mesh jump to its original baked position when playing the animation.

To preserve the simulation but move it around freely, you have to convert it to a keyframed animation. This way if parented to another object, all action will be relative to the parent's position.